# Belongs to SU or here? Question about STARTTLS or TLS/SSL

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I have a question about email security (between user and email server) - about the content, and difference between "STARTTLS" and "SSL/TLS", the options Thunderbird gives for connection security.

In a way, the question would be Super User material, since it discusses the options of a specific end-user software - Thunderbird. However, in another way the question would be IT security since on a deeper level it really is about understanding methods of securing email connections.

**So, does this sort of question belong to Super User or here in IT Security?**

*(*sigh* I'm finding [this division](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16/where-to-draw-the-line-between-it-pro-vs-end-user-questions) between non-pro / pro really confusing...)*

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing your question and seeing the answers wherever you post it.  I can't find the Q on your profile.

Comment: @makerofthings I haven't posted it yet. Ah, the dangers of postponing things for tomorrow. Thanks for reminding me, I'll post it tomorrow, or, well, maybe the day after... :)

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me it depends on what the question writer wants out of the answers.  If you're an IT person trying to define a service for your organization, you'll phrase it one way.  If you're a home user trying to figure out your options for a particular mail service out there, or whatever, you'll ask it a different way.  And some answer material will overlap.  The questions could also refer to each other.

Comment: This is very well put. "It depends on what you want out of the answers".

Answer (score 2):

Ask here.  Your question is really about the relative security impacts of these two mechanisms, so it's an IT Security question.  You'll probably get some useful answers here.