# Personal, home computer questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion

Are questions about computer security on personal, home computers on topic here, or should questions be limited to higher-level IT field questions?

Comment: See also a [similar question from the time of the private beta](http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/q/16).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with both of the answers, @this.josh and @Jeff's - but I don't think they necessarily conflict with each other.

I think it all goes back to what @nealmcb said in his answer [on this earlier question](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16/where-to-draw-the-line-between-it-pro-vs-end-user-questions/299#299): **it's all about the mindset**.

If you're looking for the expertise of a security professional, an answer that can be phrased in security / risk terms - it's on topic, even if you want to set up your own home network.
On the other hand, even if you're managing warehouses of servers, if all you want is "gimme shome script so I can foget about the stupid firewall", then I don't think this is the place for you.

Admittedly my thinking on this has evolved over the course of the beta, and I think we've seen some very good "personal computer" security questions - and also some very BAD "corporate" questions.

The **mindset** has to be the deciding factor here, however I think the issue of mindset is a difficult one to express simply to those that do not already have it. I agree with @this.josh's last point about bad FAQ...  Perhaps we should work on it some more, to try to express the issue of point of view.

As for the `... is for Information Security professionals to discuss protecting assets from threats and vulnerabilities.` - this is actually more intended for the *responders*, not the askers.

Answer (score 3):

I would argue that the equipment and location do not matter as much as the concepts in the question. Some people use 'buesiness class' computers at home, or they work from home. You also don't need to be protecting 100 machines to ask a relevent question. For example, asking about [Three-factor authentication for windows](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5075/three-factor-authentication-for-windows) is relevent. Even if it just for someone's personal laptop.  Given it is a lot more likely that a corporate IT professional managing a fleet of desktops asks a relevent question than a home user.

< humor >

As for the FAQ; [We Make Shitty FAQs. With Errors!](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/10/we-make-shitty-software-with-bugs.html)

< /humor >

Answer (score 1):

Well, per

https://security.stackexchange.com/faq

> IT Security - Stack Exchange is for Information Security professionals to discuss protecting assets from threats and vulnerabilities.

I **do not** think this should be on topic, except insofar *perhaps* as recommendations for security on a fleet of desktops maintained by a larger organization. And even then it  seems marginal.

Comment: If that's the case, is there any SE site where these questions _would_ be on-topic?

Comment: they are fine on [su]

Comment: I have added a draft edit to the [tag:security] tag over on SU to suggest the security domains which may be more appropriate here, while leaving in the ones which are more appropriate over on SU. I think it makes sense and should help puzzled users over there:-)